# How can i create generic type inherit from generic class and call it in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, generics, recursion, subclass, extends

In `kotlin` i want to understand the `<T : Person<T>>` for use the `method2`.

```
open class Person<T>
class Worker : Person<Int>()

fun <T : Comparable<T>> method1(x: T, y: T, z: T) {}
fun <T : Person<T>> method2(x: T, y: T, z: T) {}

fun main() {
    val result1 = method1(1, 2, 3) //It's OK

    val result2 = method2(Person<Int>, Person<Int>, Person<Int>) //compile error
    val result3 = method2(Worker(), Worker(), Worker()) //compile error
}
```

1. Why `result1` works and `result2` and `result3` not works?
2. Is using 'generic extends generic' is impossible? like this: `<T : Person<T>>`
3. if not so, how can i call the `method2` without compile error?
4. if it's impossible to call `method2` why does kotlin let me write this method without compile error?
   (the error is where I call the function, not where I define it)

Answer (score 0):

### 1

For `result1`, type `T` is an `Int`, which is a `Comparable<T>` so it satisfies the type bound that `T` is of type `Comparable<T>`, in this case `Comparable<Int>`.

For `result2` (once you fix the missing constructor calls), you're trying to make `T` a `Person<Int>` but this cannot possibly satisfy the type bound that `T` is of type `Person<T>`. A `Person<Int>` is not a `Person<Person<Int>>`.

Or, looking at it from the reverse point of view, you're trying to make `T` an `Int`, but an `Int` is not a `Person<Int>` so the type bound is not satisfied.

Same basic logic for `result3`.

### 2

It's possible, as you showed with the `Int` case with `result1`. Or see response 3 below.

### 3

`method2` doesn't make logical sense if `T` is `Int`. If you had a class like this:

```
class Worker : Person<Worker>()
```

Then you can call `method2` using `T` as `Worker`, just like you did for `result3`.

### 4

See response 3.